# SSRS Report fed by Stored Procedure \ IN operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I created a report to get a bunch of data. The report calls a stored procedure called sp_get52week, which gets me some totalled data about our customers. The report has 3 parameters, @Year, @Week, @SalespersonNumber. @SalespersonNumber is a parameter that can accept multiple values. The report works when only one SalesPersonNumber is selected, but not multiple. When I select multiple, I get the error:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
```

The Stored Procedure behind the report is the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Get52Week]
    @Year INT,
    @Week INT,
    @SalesPersonNumber INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  

a.[Group]
,a.[Owner]
,a.[OwnerLastName]
,SUM(a.[tot_sls_amt]) AS CYSales
,(b.[tot_sls_amt]) AS PYSales

  FROM 

[001].[MW].[MW_Submitted_Weeks_By_RBC_ROY] a
        Left Join 
            (SELECT sum([tot_sls_amt]) tot_sls_amt,[Group],[Owner] ,[SalesPersonNumber]
                 FROM [001].[MW].[MW_Submitted_Weeks_By_RBC_ROY]
                     WHERE ((Year = @Year-1 AND Week <= @Week) OR (Year = @Year - 2 AND Week > @Week)) AND cmp_status = 'A' AND [SalesPersonNumber] IN (@SalesPersonNumber)
                        group by [Group],[Owner] ,[SalesPersonNumber]) b on a.[Group] = b.[Group] and a.[Owner] = b.[Owner] and a.[SalesPersonNumber] =b.[SalesPersonNumber]



WHERE 
((Year = @Year AND Week <= @Week) OR (Year = @Year - 1 AND Week > @Week)) AND cmp_status = 'A' AND a.SalesPersonNumber IN (@SalesPersonNumber)


Group BY 
a.[Group] 
,a.[Owner]
,a.[OwnerLastName]
,(b.[tot_sls_amt])
END
```

How can I change my report to allow multiple values with a stored procedure using the IN operator?

Comment: Why not convert the stored procedure to a view or TVF? You can then filter the sales persons in the SSRS Dataset instead

Comment: Can't really convert it to a view, since it needs the parameters to run. I guess I can just throw the whole query in SSRS to feed the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show this as an answer instead

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[sp_Get52Week] (
    @Year INT,
    @Week INT
)
RETURNS table AS
RETURN (
    SELECT a.[Group]
          ,a.[Owner]
          ,a.[OwnerLastName]
          ,a.[SalesPersonNumber]
          ,SUM(a.[tot_sls_amt]) AS CYSales
          ,(b.[tot_sls_amt]) AS PYSales
    FROM [001].[MW].[MW_Submitted_Weeks_By_RBC_ROY] a
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum([tot_sls_amt]) tot_sls_amt
                          ,[Group]
                          ,[Owner] 
                          ,[SalesPersonNumber]
                    FROM [001].[MW].[MW_Submitted_Weeks_By_RBC_ROY]
                    WHERE ((Year = @Year-1 AND Week <= @Week) OR 
                           (Year = @Year - 2 AND Week > @Week)) 
                          AND cmp_status = 'A' 
                    GROUP BY [Group]
                            ,[Owner] 
                            ,[SalesPersonNumber]) b 
             ON a.[Group] = b.[Group] 
                AND a.[Owner] = b.[Owner] 
                AND a.[SalesPersonNumber] = b.[SalesPersonNumber]
    WHERE ((Year = @Year AND Week <= @Week) 
           OR (Year = @Year - 1 AND Week > @Week)) 
          AND cmp_status = 'A' 
    GROUP BY a.[Group] 
            ,a.[Owner]
            ,a.[OwnerLastName]
            ,a.[SalesPersonNumber]
            ,(b.[tot_sls_amt])
)
```

In the report you do

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[sp_Get52Week](@Year, @Week)
WHERE [SalesPersonNumber] IN (@SalesPersonNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

The IN operator does not work with multiple values in one parameter. Furthermore, your `@SalesPersonNumber` parameter is of data type `INT`, which only accepts one value.

To work around this, what you could do is declare the @SalesPersonNumber as a `VARCHAR(MAX)` datatype, and then change your filter to something like this:

```
WHERE ... AND 
    (',' + @SalesPersonNumber + ',' LIKE
     '%,' + CAST(a.SalesPersonNumber AS VARCHAR) + ',%')
```

This assumes that you're assigning a comma-separated list of values to the @SalesPersonNumber parameter. You might need to use some SSRS array-to-string functionality to achieve this (take a look at the SSRS JOIN-function).

What the above code essentially does, is to check whether the SalesPersonNumber in your table matches one of the comma-separated numbers in the `@SalesPersonNumber`-string.